# How to rename Apple mouse using Ubuntu?

Tags: 22.04, mouse, laptop

System: Ubuntu Desktop 22.04LTS. Hardware: Asus UX305FA laptop.

My mother-in-law had an old Apple AIO, recently replaced. She gave me her old Apple wireless mouse (model A1657). I've paired it with my Ubuntu 22.04LTS laptop and works nicely.

Minor irritant - it identifes as 'her' mouse (listed as Geraldine's mouse #1 in BT settings).
Is there any way to rename it in Ubuntu? Doesn't affect functionality at all so I don't really mind if I can't. I don't have an Apple computer if that's required. Clicking on the device in BT settings shows me the address and gives me the option to remove the device / disconnect, but I can't see a rename option.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a device alias using bluetoothctl and the command `set-alias'

```
$ blutoothctl
[Geraldine's mouse]# set-alias "newname"
[Geraldine's mouse]# quit
$
```

New name can only be one word I think. I couldn't put a space in mine.

You can also use a mac or mac book with an older OS (before Catalina) to rename it. Go to bluetooth settings on the mac and connect the mouse. right click on it to rename. GL

Comment: Thank you. Yes, that works (I don't have access to a mac here, so used bluetoothctl). I found you can have spaces - but you have to escape them (and apostrophes): so I changed it to 'Will's mouse' by entering 'Will\'s\ mouse'.

Answer (score -1):

Once you are in the bluetoothctl menu it may not be obvious how to rename another device from there:

```
$ blutoothctl
[Geraldine's mouse]# set-alias "newname"
[CHG] Device 84:AC:FE:FF:9B:8C Alias: newname
Changing newname succeeded
[Geraldine's mouse]# devices
Device 84:AC:FE:FF:9B:8C Geraldine's mouse
Device E4:32:7F:1A:FF:6A Geraldine's Keyboard
[Geraldine's mouse]# connect "E4:32:7F:1A:FF:6A"
Attempting to connect to E4:32:7F:1A:FF:6A
Connection successful
[Geraldine's Keyboard]#
```

Now you can rename the next device.

Note that the name changes will not be seen until you quit the utility and restart it.